# Pentaho data Integration - cut a string after comma (not in a fixed position)

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

In Pentaho data-integration I need (from a Excel Input) to replace a specific string.

I need to delete all characters after the first comma (it can be in a casual position), like this:

`"A,b,c,f" -> "A"`

`"aaaaa,bbbb,cccc" -> "aaaaa"`

I've tried `string cut` but it allows meto cut after a specific number of characters (not a specific word or character, such as comma).

In my sql is : `SUBSTRING_INDEX(technician, ',', 1)`.. but what would it be with Pentaho?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Replace in strings step, set it to search and replace using RegEx, set the search RegEx to ([^,]*),.* and set the replace field as $1.